# Can't check the content of an email

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read the content of an `mbox` file and compare it with a list of words also read from a different file. I believe the problem is I am reading them wrong, since the output does not match what I expect knowing the content of the files.

I have tried to read them both as `rb` and `r` with no luck. I then tried to put the `txt` file into a `list`. Anyway the `mbox` file cannot be inserted into a list. As further test, I tried to read the content of the email by using the `get_payload()` function but it returns bytes that are not useful to me.

```
# Opening the file that contains the balcklisted words and printing it 
with open("blacklist.txt",'r') as afile:
    buf=afile.read()
    print(buf)

# Opening the mbox files
mbox = mailbox.mbox('Andishe.mbox')

# To read the content of the mbox file when its a multiple messages
for message in mbox:
    if message.is_multipart():
        print ("from   :",message['from'])
        print ("to   :",message['to'])
        content = message.as_string()
        # print(content)
    else:
        print ("from   :",message['from'])
        print ("to   :",message['to'])
        content = message.as_string()
        # print(content)


# To check and see if the black listed words are inside the content of the email 
for file in content:
    if file in buf:
        print("file contains blacklisted words" + file)
    else:
        print("file does not contain blacklisted words")
```

I would expect the results to be like this:

```
some black listed word
file contains blacklisted words + the black listed word
```

But I am stuck in a loop that keeps printing itself, the following is a part of what gets printed:

```
file contains blacklisted wordsr
file contains blacklisted wordso
file contains blacklisted wordsm
file contains blacklisted words
```

I have no idea what those `r`, `o`, `m` stand for or where they are coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out where I was going wrong:

1- I was reading the content of the txt file wrong. I should have used this:

```
    blacklist=[]
    for line in afile:
        blacklist.append(line.strip('\n'))
```

this way, I was getting rid of the end of line charterer and also keeping each line to a word

2- I was also not doing my for loop wrong, since I did not append the content of the mbox file. this fixed the issue:

```
content_string = ''.join(content)
content_string = content_string.lower()
for word in blacklist:
    if word.lower() in content_string:
        print("This black listed word exists in content         : ",word)
```